# "The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value" error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
< asp:Button runat="server" ID='<%# string.Format("btn/{0}", Eval("category")) %>'  OnClick="btnMark_Click" CommandName='<%#Eval("pin_id") %>' />
```

I get "The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value" error when I use this. I searched online, some said remove runat="server" will solve the error, but it will cause my onclick event not triggering when clicked.

Comment: I have added your line of code, and it works for me

Comment: Why you need Button Id set on runtime.? Could you explain?

Comment: @AsadAli Perhaps his buttons are within a template (ListView, Repeater, etc), and wants to access the buttons in C# using unique IDs.